# Test to check if attribute is assigned fails

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying out some of the exercises over on [exercism](http://exercism.io/). Each exercise comes with a set of pre-written tests that we need to make pass. The problem I'm currently working on asks us to write a Robot class. Each robot should come with a method called name that sets a default name. I'm doing that like this:

```
class Robot
  attr_accessor :name

  def self.name
    @name = DateTime.now.strftime("%y%^b%k%M%S")
    @name
  end
end
```

The problem is that the first test (I'm skipping over the rest for now) keeps failing. Here's the test:

```
  def test_has_name
    # rubocop:disable Lint/AmbiguousRegexpLiteral
    assert_match /^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/, Robot.new.name
    # rubocop:enable Lint/AmbiguousRegexpLiteral
  end
```

I'm not using the rubocop gem so I've left the commented lines as is. The test fails with this error:

```
  1) Failure:
RobotTest#test_has_name [robot-name/robot_name_test.rb:7]:
Expected /^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/ to match nil.
```

I suppose the biggest problem is that I don't really understand the error and I don't know if I need to install rubocop and uncomment those lines above or of my code is just plain wrong. Any help at all with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is number of issues with your code.

First, you define accessor `:name`, but you don't have `initialize` method.

What you have defined, is a class method `name`, which would work if you call `Robot.name`.

To make your class work, it should look like this:

```
class Robot

  def initialize
    @name = DateTime.now.strftime("%y%^b%k%M%S")
  end

end

Robot.new.name
#=> "15MAY150035"
```

Or You would do

```
class Robot

  def name
    DateTime.now.strftime("%y%^b%k%M%S")
  end

end

Robot.new.name
#=> "15MAY150649"
```

Also, in Ruby last line in method is already what would be `return`ed, so you don't have to write `@name` here:

```
  def self.name
    @name = DateTime.now.strftime("%y%^b%k%M%S")
    @name # useless
  end
```

Furthermore, variable `@name` is useless here, since method `name` either way will return `DateTime` object.

You have to make sure you understand what is what in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I guess I was a little confused. I did as you asked (going with the second option - the method called name) and the test is still failing with: `RobotTest#test_has_name [robot-name/robot_name_test.rb:7]:
Expected /^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$/ to match "15MAY140549".` - Would this have something to do with the two lines that are commented out in the test?

Comment: @SoSimple Testing DateTime objects is a tricky thing, and I am not sure that it is the best time for you to dive into mocks and stubs.. Try to 1) understand what is going on in my explanation; 2) Change the name to some static string, and then test against it

Comment: The regex matches two upcase letters at the beginning followed by 3 digits. E.g. "AA345"

Comment: @jphager2 Is that's what's happening? Okay, that was confusing the hell out of me. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I'll definitely play around with some hardcoded strings and thank you so much for explaining. I can see now how I was misusing `attr_accessor` and `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code defines `name` to be a method on the `Robot` *class* (that's what the `self` indicates; and `@name` here will be setting a member variable on the class object). You need to provide a way for each *instance* to have a name.

As a secondary concern, your method changes the name everytime `name` is called. You probably want to set it once (when the robot is `initialize`d, probably!), then return that each time.

Comment: I can be more explicit if you want, or you can try to put what I've suggested into practice yourself.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I removed `self` and I've refactored according to @AndreyDeineko 's suggestions. As I explained to him, the test is still failing. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Also, I just remembered, I actually want a new name generated everytime `name` is called. That part was intentional. Just fyi, but thank you for pointing it out anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is a class method. Which means that `Robot.name` will give you the name, while `Robot.new.name` is `nil`.

You want to use:

```
def name
  #code
end
```

Instead of `self.name`.

You can also set name in the `initialize` method:

```
def initialize 
  @name = 'RB123'
end
```